# Tables to CSS....Layout sliced from Photoshop

Tags: css, slice, photoshop, tablelayout

I am messing around and created a neat web layout in Photoshop. I then sliced it up and exported all of the Images and HTML to Dreamweaver. However, it turns my layout into tables. This is a problem because I can't get it to fit all screen resolutions. Does anyone have a quick fix or some advice on how to get my slicing converted to CSS?

Comment: http://doctype.com/ is the place for this question.

Comment: If you're not happy with what Dreamweaver gives you (hint: nobody is), you'll have to do it yourself or find somebody who does it for you.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't going to get an automated thing like that to work the way you want it to.  It's why I started coding.  When slicing your psd think about it in the layers it is in, then you will have to figure out how to css it all together.  It's alot to learn, but once you get your awesome psd working as an active web page you will realize how worth it it was.